# How can I do self-feed a vector into a function iteratively using do-while loop in c++?

Tags: c++, function, loops, vector, while-loop

if I start with a `vector<double> myVec` and suppose there's a function `myFunction` that

when myVec goes into, returns a vector of same length, but 
to illustrate what I need to do,

suppose I obtain `vector<double> myVec2 = myFunction(vector<double> myVec)`

then I obtain `vector<double> myVec3 = myFunction(vector<double> myVec2)`

then I obtain `vector<double> myVec4 = myFunction(vector<double> myVec3)` ... etc

until a condition on i'th myVec is met, thus say `condition(myVec8) == true`

how can I do so?

so far, I've tried

```
do{
   myVec = myFunction(myVec);
}while( condition(myVec) == true);
```

but nothing can be printed

Comment: What do you mean by *"nothing can be printed"*?

Comment: you want to copy vector to vector?

Comment: you can directly copy a vector why do you need a function?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code you posted. Can you post a working example of what you are unable to achieve? Also you may want to use `std::move` on your *vectors* when doing this to prevent unnecessary copying.

Comment: Oh wow it was so stupid. It should've been !condition and I have no idea how I didn't manage to see it. It's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but this code works fine for me:

```
std::vector<int> process_vector(std::vector<int> v)
{
    // add one random element to the vector
    v.push_back(hol::random_number(0, 10));
    return v;
}

bool condition(std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    // end when sum of elements is larger than 100
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0) > 100;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    // use `std::move` to avoid copying the vector
    while(!condition(v))
        v = process_vector(std::move(v)); // move vector in

    // print the results    
    for(auto i: v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 4 1 4 9 8 0 7 6 8 3 4 7 2 3 1 7 3 1 2 4 0 8 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step To Follow  self-feed a vector into a function iteratively using do-while loop in c++**

---

1. Declare and initialize your vector with the initial values.
2. Define your function that takes the vector as an argument and performs some
   operations on it.
3. Create a do-while loop that iterates until a certain condition is met.
4. Within the loop, call your function with the current state of the vector.
5. Update the vector based on the results of the function.
6. Check the termination condition to determine whether to continue the loop.

---

**Example :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void incrementVector(std::vector<int>& vec) {
for (int& element : vec) {
element++;
}
}

int main() {
std::vector<int> myVector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

bool continueLoop = true;
do {
    // Call the function with the current state of the vector
    incrementVector(myVector);

    // Print the updated vector
    for (int element : myVector) {
        std::cout << element << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Update the termination condition based on some criteria
    if (myVector[0] >= 10) {
        continueLoop = false;
    }
} while (continueLoop);

return 0;
}
```

---

In this example, the incrementVector function is used to increment each element of the vector. The loop continues until the first element of the vector reaches a value greater than or equal to 10. The vector is updated within each iteration, and the updated values are printed.

Answer (score -2):

would this work ?

```
while( true ){
    if( condition(myVec) ){
        break;
    }else{
        // do stuff with vector
        myVector = myFunction(myVector);
    }
}
```

or...
Maybe you can use recursion for this....

```
void handle_vector( vector<double> myVec ){
    if( !condition(myVec) ){
        // do stuff with myVector
        handle_vector( myFunction(myVec) );
    }
}
```

Comment: He already has functional code that already does exactly what the OP claims they want; reinventing `do`/`while` poorly is not necessary; the problem is in code we haven't been provided.